# AWS Cloudwatch make no data received okay

Tags: amazon-web-services, alarm, amazon-cloudwatch

AWS Alarms support three states: OK, INSUFFICIENT_DATA and ALARM. I have a metric that if data is ever received should produce an alarm. That's easy enough. The problem is if no data is received that should be an all clear. But the only way I see to program this is for no data to be INSUFFICIENT_DATA, which looks like an outage (and does indeed mean an outage for the rest of our applications).

Right now the best solution we have is to send 0's so it registers as OK instead of INSUFFICIENT_DATA. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't publishing a metric there is no way for CloudWatch to know if you're doing it on purpose or there is a service outage which is causing the metric to stop flowing.

A cleaner solution would be having a heartbeat metric per application (e.g sending 1 values periodically) and creating additional alarms on these. These alarms would show you if any of your applications is down and you could use your original alarm to fire if data is received.